# How to set data-internal time and height on bootstrap carousel?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I tried to set the height and data-interval time but it won't effect. and image also not sliding. How can i fix that?

```
.carousel img{
   height: 50%;
 }
.carousel-inner .carousel-item {
   transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease;
   transition: transform 2s ease;
   transition: transform 2s ease, -webkit-transform 2s ease;
}

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="/assets/images/slide1.jpg" alt="First slide">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="/assets/images/slide2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="/assets/images/slide3.jpeg" alt="Third slide">
  </div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to set time interval

---

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 1000 * 5 // 5 sec (1000ms * 5 = 5 sec)
});
```

**or**

You can use the `data-interval` attribute in HTML tag, like this:

```
<div class="carousel" data-interval="100">
```

### Change height of carousel

---

```
.carousel-item {
  height: 150px;
}

.carousel-item img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 150px;
}
```

### Working demo

---

```css
.carousel-item {
  height: 150px;
}

.carousel-item img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="100">
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKdkZ.jpg" alt="First slide">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeCR9.jpg" alt="Second slide">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sto7j.jpg" alt="Third slide">
  </div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

Comment: <div class="carousel" data-interval="10000"> this code doesn't work.

Comment: Properly worked  @devanshi please try the working demo.

Comment: I added ```<div class="carousel" data-interval="100">``` to understand the interval.

Comment: Are you included external CSS and JS (Bootstrap,Jquery,Popper) ? This demo is working correctly.

Comment: Please check properly.

Comment: Is your image sliding?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219697/discussion-between-rayees-ac-and-devanshi).